# How to Encrypt a virtual machine on Mac?

Tags: virtualization, disk-encryption, macos, truecrypt

I'd like to encrypt a virtual machine that I will be creating. The host OS is Mac OS X and I am running VMware Fusion. I know Trucrypt is usually used but I have never used it before and haven't found any reliable instructions, at least not for Mac. What is the procedure?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want the host to encrypt the virtual hard drive or you want the VM to encrypt its own virtual hard drive? (In which case we need to know the guest OS).

Comment: @user2675345 host encrypt the virtual hard drive

Answer (score 2):

Truecrypt can be used, version 7.1a I believe. Version 7.2 can only decrypt. As the status of Truecrypt is uncertain, you might want to look at the built in Apple alternative: an encrypted DMG. It works easier in my experience. I guess both are equally safe when your harddisk is stolen, but I have no idea what is more secure when stolen by the NSA.

For normal use, create a DMG!

See http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1578

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Truecrypt volume. The documentation of how to set one up can be found here.

http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/truecrypt-volume

The type you want is a `File-hosted (container)`. This will act like a "very large" file on your computer. You decrypt it and mount it using Truecrypt. Once it is mounted it acts like external storage media. You can move your vmwarevm folder for the VM you want to encrypt to the Truecrypt volume and then symlink the place where you usually mount the volume back to the vmware directory.

i.e.

```
ln -s /Volumes/my_tc_container/my_vm.vmwarevm /Users/me/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/my_vm.vmwarevm
```

The advantage of using Truecrypt is

- It is open source, reduced risk of there being a backdoor and if one was ever found you would hear about it very very quickly.
- It is cross platform, if you even need to mount your Truecrypt volume on Windows or Linux Truecrypt works the exact same way on those platforms.
- It's popular, if you ever need help it will be easy to find someone who knows a thing or two about Truecrypt.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like the Truecrypt option is no longer viable: http://krebsonsecurity.com/2014/05/true-goodbye-using-truecrypt-is-not-secure/